# Setup Marklogic connector for hadoop in Windows machine?

Tags: hadoop, marklogic, marklogic-9

I need to setup MarkLogic connector for Hadoop for sending the ml files to HDFS storage and retrieving them.

I went through one of the [ML document](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/mapreduce/quickstart) where they had mentioned in `required software` section it requires Linux:

> The MarkLogic Connector for Hadoop is a Java-only API and is only available on Linux. You can use the connector with any of the Hadoop distributions listed below. Though the Hadoop MapReduce Connector is only supported on the Hadoop distributions listed below, it may work with other distributions, such as an equivalent version of Apache Hadoop.

So, does this mean I can't achieve this on a Windows machine?

Comment: You would need to install Hadoop on Windows, which isn't officially supported by Hadoop.  Java is cross platform, so the connector shouldn't care

Comment: Thanks@cricket_007. So you mean I can able to send the ml documents from my windows machine to hadoop HDFS which is running in my machine .

Comment: I don't see why not. Also, not clear how your Hadoop was installed, but  Cygwin is a Linux subsystem in Windows